# How can I modify a QtableWidget which is on a QMainWindow from a QGraphicsView method?

Tags: pyqt5

Essentially I created a QMainWindow which has a Splitter which, in turn, has on its left side a QTableWidget and on the right side a QGraphicsView.

I have also created a method to zoom in and out in the QGraphicsView. Now, I want to resize the height of the rows depending on the amount of zoom provided by the user.

```
    class MyWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        # Main characteristics of the window
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1000, 700)

        #User Interface
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        #Creation of table and timeline splitter
        self.table_and_view_splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter()
        self.table_and_view_splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)

            #Creation of metadata table
        self.create_table()
        self.table_and_view_splitter.addWidget(self.table)

            #Creation of View and Scene for timeline
        self.create_view()
        self.table_and_view_splitter.addWidget(self.view)

        # Creation of vertical splitter

        self.vertical_splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter()
        self.vertical_splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.vertical_splitter.insertWidget(1, self.table_and_view_splitter)

        # Choosing the sizes of the upper and lower widgets of the Qsplitter
        self.sizes_list = [100, 5000]
        self.vertical_splitter.setSizes(self.sizes_list)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.vertical_splitter)

    def create_table(self):

        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.table.setRowCount(100)

        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            self.table.setRowHeight(i, 10)

    def create_view(self):
        self.view = viewFor()
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.addEllipse(1, 1, 10, 10)
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)

class viewFor(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self):
        super(viewFor, self).__init__()

        self.drag = False
        self.setTransformationAnchor(self.NoAnchor)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):

        self.setTransformationAnchor(self.AnchorUnderMouse)

        zoom_in_factor = 1.1
        zoom_out_factor = 1 / zoom_in_factor

        # Save the scene pos
        old_position = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

        if QApplication.keyboardModifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier:# CTRL + Scroll -> X and Y Zoom
            # Zoom
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                zoom_factor = zoom_in_factor
            else:
                zoom_factor = zoom_out_factor
            self.scale(zoom_factor, zoom_factor)
            #HERE I WANT TO RESIZE THE ROWS HEIGHT ACCORDING TO THE zoom_factor

            # Get the new position
            new_position = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

            # Move scene to old position
            delta = new_position - old_position
            self.translate(delta.x(), delta.y())

        else:# Only Scroll -> only X Zoom
            # Zoom
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                zoom_factor = zoom_in_factor
            else:
                zoom_factor = zoom_out_factor
            self.scale(zoom_factor, 1)

            # Get the new position
            new_position = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

            # Move scene to old position
            delta = new_position - old_position
            self.translate(delta.x(), delta.y())

app = QApplication([])
foo = MyWindow()
foo.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to emit a signal whenever the scale is changed, and [`QHeaderView.setDefaultSectionSize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#defaultSectionSize-prop) for the vertical header. Note that you should probably use [`setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Fixed)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSectionResizeMode) to avoid user resizing (or just leave it to `Interactive`, but certainly don't use `Stretch` or `ResizeToContents`).

You should obviously ensure that the range is valid or find your own algorithm (that sanitizes the value to a valid range that has at least a minimum of 1).
In this case I used the default original value and multiplied it using the scale factor of the view's transformation (see [QTransform > rendering graphics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtransform.html#rendering-graphics) about the meaning of the transformation matrix).

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        # Main characteristics of the window
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1000, 700)

        #User Interface
        self.initUI()
        self.view.scaleChanged.connect(self.resizeRows)
        self.defaultSize = self.table.verticalHeader().defaultSectionSize()

    def resizeRows(self, scale):
        self.table.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(scale * self.defaultSize)


class viewFor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    scaleChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(float)

    # ...

    def wheelEvent(self, event):

        self.setTransformationAnchor(self.AnchorUnderMouse)

        zoom_in_factor = 1.1
        zoom_out_factor = 1 / zoom_in_factor

        # Save the scene pos
        old_position = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

        if event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:# CTRL + Scroll -> X and Y Zoom
            # Zoom
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                zoom_factor = zoom_in_factor
            else:
                zoom_factor = zoom_out_factor
            self.scale(zoom_factor, zoom_factor)

            # emit the signal based on the transformation scale factor
            self.scaleChanged.emit(self.transform().m11())
            # ...
```

Note that you don't need to use `QApplication.keyboardModifiers`, as you can access `modifiers()` of all keyboard/mouse events.

Comment: It works perfectly! I would have spent several days trying to figure this out.Thank you very much!

Comment: @Tomas You're welcome! I suggest you to read the documentation about all item views, not only the QTableView (and its "cousins" QTreeView and QListView), but also their ancestor QAbstractItemView and the QHeaderView used on both tables (`horizontalHeader()` and `verticalHeader()`) and trees (`header()`).